# ARMv8 (Aarch64) NEON Compilation with GCC

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arm, simd, neon

I would like to compile a program that uses float64x2_t intrinsic data types aiming for ARM NEON. However, I am unable to do this since compiler does not recognize float64x2_t data types.

I am  arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc (version 4.8.3)to compile a .cpp file which included "arm_neon.h". However, As I see there are two types of arm_neon.h, one for ARMv6-7 and one for ARMv8. The GCC I uses seems to have the first one, therefore it is normal to expect not recognizing float64x2_t.

Which compiler(GCC preferred) should I use in order to work with float64x2_t types aiming for ARMv8?

Comment: To compile AArch64 code you need, perhaps unsurprisingly, an AArch64 compiler (with GCC it's an entirely separate target from AArch32/legacy ARM).

Comment: which probably implies a somewhat newer compiler than GCC 4.8.3.

Comment: @marko Nah, I know I have an AArch64 4.8.3 on an old box at home (since Linaro stopped releasing i686 binaries after 14.01 and I can't be bothered building my own)

Comment: 4.8 was the first GCC release to support AArch64, but you will likely find that the code generated by a more modern toolchain is much higher quality.